# java thread pool exectur perform execute(runnable) method once

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a distributed multiplayer game. The architecture is a classic server-client one and it uses sockets to communicate. I'd want to create a thread pool in the server to match each client to a different thread through the respective socket. The problem is that the execute(Runnable) method only works once! This is a piece of code:

Server:

```
public class Server extends ThreadPoolExecutor{
  Server() throws IOException{
    super(MIN_POOL_SIZE, MAX_POOL_SIZE, TIME_ALIVE, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new  ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(MAX_POOL_SIZE));
    listener=new ServerSocket(PORT_NO);
    listener.setSoTimeout(SERVER_TIMEOUT);
    clients=new ArrayList<ClientConnection>();
    System.out.println("Listening on port "+PORT_NO);
  }

 void runServer(){
   Socket socket;
   ClientConnection connection;
   try{
      while(true){
        socket=listener.accept();
        System.out.println("client accettato");
        connection=new ClientConnection(socket, this);
        System.out.println("creata la connection");
        try{
           execute(connection);
           //clients.add(connection);
           //  System.out.println("Accepted connection");
           //  connection.send("Welcome!");
        }
        catch(RejectedExecutionException e){
          //connection.send("Server is full!!!");
          socket.close();
        }
      }
   }
    catch (IOException ioe){
      try{listener.close();}catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      System.out.println("Time to join the match expired");
      //init();
    }
  }
}
```

Runnable to execute:

```
public class ClientConnection extends Player implements Runnable{
  // private static final boolean BLACK=false;
  // private static final boolean WHITE=true;
  // private int ammo;
  // private boolean team;

  private volatile BufferedReader br;
  private volatile PrintWriter pw;
  private volatile Server server;
  private volatile Socket socket;

  public ClientConnection(Socket s, Server srv) throws IOException{
    super(10+(int)Math.random()*30, true);
    socket=s;
    server=srv;
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
    pw = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
    System.out.println("costruzione nuovo socket");
  }

  @Override
  public void run(){
    System.out.println("run execution");
    while(true);
  }

  public void send(String message){
    pw.println(message);
  }
}
```

The problem is that the line "run execution" in the run() method is printed once. I don't understand which is the problem, is there anyone who could help me?
Thank you ahead!

Comment: And how many would you expect ? It is executed, and thread falls into infinite loop with while(true) that does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
System.out.println("run execution");
while(true);
```

This is the problem. Why after printing to Console, you go to infinite loop? I assume you want to execute print statement unlimited times. May be you want to do something like this?

```
while (true) {
      System.out.println("run execution");
}
```